# Rearranging a Staircase Grid into a Square

Tags: geometry, puzzle

[image]

Is there any way to rearrange the above "staircase" grid into **three** pieces that can be rearranged into the 6x6 square grid below it? I have tried this problem for over six hours and have not arrived at any solution. There *has* to be some general strategy in approaching this problem other than brute force, right??

I would appreciate any and all help--hints, suggestions, anything... I've gone mad trying to solve it

:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\def\r{\color{red}{1}}\def\b{\color{blue}{2}}\def\g{\color{green}{3}}
\matrix{\r\cr \r&\r\cr \r&\r&\r\cr \r&\r&\r&\r\cr \r&\r&\r&\g&\g\cr
  \r&\r&\r&\g&\g&\g\cr \b&\b&\b&\g&\g&\g&\g\cr
  \b&\b&\b&\g&\g&\g&\g&\g\cr}$$
can be rearranged as
$$\matrix{\g&\g&\g&\g&\b&\b\cr \g&\g&\g&\g&\b&\b\cr \g&\g&\g&\r&\b&\b\cr
  \g&\g&\r&\r&\r&\r\cr \g&\r&\r&\r&\r&\r\cr \r&\r&\r&\r&\r&\r\cr}$$

Comment: Wow.. How did you do it so quickly?? Would you care to elaborate on your approach/thought process? Thanks!

Comment: I started with the realisation that the three corners of the staircase must be in different pieces, because any two of them are too far apart to fit in the square if they are confined to one piece.  Extending this idea, the three squares at the top of the staircase must all be in one piece, likewise the three squares at the right, likewise the four at bottom left.  After that it was really only trial and error, building up the pieces in both staircase and square a few bits at a time and making sure they have the same shapes.

Answer (score -1):

You first the 6 by 6 on the staircase. Even thought it is not total, you can take the left over pieces and do it.

Comment: Tried that. Unsuccessful, unfortunately